# Why is GitVersion "Skipping fetching" and how can I make it not skip?

Tags: .net, git, teamcity, gitversion

I've setup [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) as a build step in my TeamCity build configuration.

1. Given that the most recent version tag on master is v1.2.3
2. And TeamCity runs a build based on the latest commit on master
3. When I later tag that commit with a new version tag: v1.2.4
4. Then when I manually run the TeamCity build, GitVersion ignores the new version tag and again outputs the previous version.

In the build log I see the following message:

> INFO [05/10/16 7:52:05:74] Skipping fetching, if GitVersion does not calculate your version as expected you might need to allow fetching or use dynamic repositories

Why is GitVersion skipping fetching? How can I *"allow fetching"*?

Note:

- The VCS root is configured to run "automatically on client".
- The GitVersion build step is based on the [GitVersion TeamCity meta-runner](https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack/tree/master/gitversion).
- <s>I would rather not use dynamic repositories as I'd like to understand what's going on</s>.

**UPDATE:**
I get the exact same behavior even when I use dynamic repositories. :(

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation here:

http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-server-support/build-server/teamcity/

You need to either use `agent checkout` or configure the use of a dynamic repository.

Comment: Thanks, but I've followed the instructions for `agent checkout` there. The `vcsid` variable is promoted to `env.Git_branch`. I also have the vcs root set to build "automatically on agent". Any other ideas aside from using a dynamic repository?

Comment: Have you altered anything else within the TeamCity VCS Configuration?  Or is everything else the default?  In order to correctly figure out the current version number, GitVersion needs all the relevant history of the project, if this doesn't exist, GitVersion fetches this history as part of it's execution.  Do you get the correct version number if you run GitVersion locally on your repo?

Comment: Default TC config as far as I can tell. GitVersion in working dir returns the wrong version as well. Any idea what the error message means when it says "allow fetching"? How can I allow it? Isn't this a bug in GitVersion?

Comment: I've just configured GitVersion to use a dynamic repository - This did not resolve the issue. I get the same behavior and log message.